# Why some font can be not found?

Tags: fonts, xetex, packages, fontspec

I set font in the document so

```
\setmainfont{Akrobat}
%or
\setmainfont{Akrobat SemiBold}
%or
\setmainfont{Cormorant}
%or
\setmainfont{Cormorant Medium}
%or
\setmainfont{Cormorant Garamond SemiBold}
```

It's all works

```
\setmainfont{Coval}
```

Work too, but

```
\setmainfont{Coval Light} %Book, Medium
```

etc. get an error. Work only 'Coval Italic'

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Coval Book" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.12 ...nt[ItalicFont = {Coval Light}]{Coval Book}
                                                  % Основной шри�...
```

Where does this problem?
Font have I downloaded from https://smartfonts.com/coval.font

It is supposed that I should have these styles.

Comment: Better use file names instead of font names -- easier to find the correct name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, don't work any variant   "\setmainfont[Path=/home/ekkl/.fonts/Coval]{Coval-Light.otf}% Основной шрифт текста"

Comment: Something wrong with the font, maybe? Whatever you manage fonts with, what does it say about it? Can you use it in other applications? What does FontForge say?

Answer (score 1):

The font manager did not correctly display the font name. Instead of the family name and style of the inscription. For all fonts this coincided with the names, but not for these.

If somebody has similar problem, see correct font name in FontForge. Screenshot was added.

[image]
[image]

In Font Viewer names are displayed similar (with spaces), but in FontForge — different:

[image]
[image]

The font names have a "-" instead of a space.
Based on the given name in FontForge, I can write for Akrobat:

```
\setmainfont[]{Akrobat Light}% Correct name
\setmainfont[]{Akrobat-Light}% Also the correct name
```

But for Coval:

```
\setmainfont[]{Coval Light}% Incorrect name, missing in FontForge
\setmainfont[]{Coval-Light}% Correct name. So only!
```

---

I apologize for the screenshots in Ukrainian, I hope you understand, basis of interfaces